# EnvironmentEvent macro doesn't complete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, macros, event-handling, outlining

I'm working in Visual Studio 2008 and I would like for Edit > Outlining > Collapse to Definitions to be run whenever I open a file.  It would be nice if, after that, all regions were expanded.  I tried the code that Kyralessa offered in a comment on [The Problem with Code Folding](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-problem-with-code-folding/), and that works very nicely as a macro that I have to run manually.  I tried to expand this macro to act as an event by placing the following code in the EnvironmentEvents module in the Macro IDE:

```
Public Sub documentEvents_DocumentOpened(ByVal Document As EnvDTE.Document) Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened
    Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions")
    DTE.SuppressUI = True
    Dim objSelection As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    objSelection.StartOfDocument()
    Do While objSelection.FindText("#region", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText)
    Loop
    objSelection.StartOfDocument()
    DTE.SuppressUI = False
End Sub
```

However, this does not seem to do anything when I open a file from my Solution in VS.  To test that the macro was getting run, I put a `MsgBox()` statement in that subroutine and noticed that code before `Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions")` ran fine, but nothing seemed to get hit after that line.  When I debugged and set a breakpoint within the subroutine, I would hit F10 to continue to the next line and control would leave the subroutine as soon as that `ExecuteCommand` line ran.  Despite this, that line seems to do nothing, i.e. it doesn't collapse the outlining.

I also tried using just `DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions")` within the subroutine but with no luck.

This question tries to obtain the same end result as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293806/is-there-a-way-to-specify-outlining-defaults-in-visual-studio-so-that-a-file-open/), but I'm asking about what I might be doing wrong in my event-handling macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the document is not really active when the event fires. One solution is to use a "fire once" timer to execute the code a short delay after the DocumentOpened event occured:

```
Dim DocumentOpenedTimer As Timer

Private Sub DocumentEvents_DocumentOpened(ByVal Document As EnvDTE.Document) Handles DocumentEvents.DocumentOpened
    DocumentOpenedTimer = New Timer(AddressOf ExpandRegionsCallBack, Nothing, 200, Timeout.Infinite)
End Sub

Private Sub ExpandRegionsCallBack(ByVal state As Object)
    ExpandRegions()
    DocumentOpenedTimer.Dispose()
End Sub

Public Sub ExpandRegions()
    Dim Document As EnvDTE.Document = DTE.ActiveDocument
    If (Document.FullName.EndsWith(".vb") OrElse Document.FullName.EndsWith(".cs")) Then
        If Not DTE.ActiveWindow.Caption.ToUpperInvariant.Contains("design".ToUpperInvariant) Then
            Document.DTE.SuppressUI = True
            Document.DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.CollapsetoDefinitions")
            Dim objSelection As TextSelection = Document.Selection
            objSelection.StartOfDocument()
            Do While objSelection.FindText("#region", vsFindOptions.vsFindOptionsMatchInHiddenText)
            Loop
            objSelection.StartOfDocument()
            Document.DTE.SuppressUI = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I haven't tested it extensively, so there might be some bugs... Also, I added a check to verify that the active document is a C# or VB source code (not tested with VB though) and that it's not in design mode.
Anyway, hope it works for you...

Comment: Holy crap, it works!  I had to add an `Imports System.Threading` line in my EnvironmentEvents macro for `Timer` and `Timeout`, but it works!  I open my CS files now and, after about a second, all my definitions are collapsed.  Thanks!

Comment: I have noticed that when I open a new Solution and it remembers what files I had open last time, the macro IDE has to close because of an error.

Comment: Yep, I got the error too. I tried to solve the problem but couldn't find a solution and I've already spend too much time on it. If I think of something else, I'll post it. In the meantime, you could just use a boolean (set to false in the Solution_Opened event) to activate/deactivate the feature and bind it to a keyboard shortcut.